# Trim a suffix before applying auto-mode-alist

Tags: auto-mode-alist

I am pretty sure there was a way to remove backup suffixes like `~` and `.bak` before mode detection, but I just can't find it anymore...

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `elisp-index-search` <kbd>RET</kbd> `auto-mode-alist` says:

```
 When you visit a file whose expanded file name (*note File Name
 Expansion::), with version numbers and backup suffixes removed
 using ‘file-name-sans-versions’ (*note File Name Components::),
 matches a REGEXP, ‘set-auto-mode’ calls the corresponding
 MODE-FUNCTION.  This feature enables Emacs to select the proper
 major mode for most files.
```

`file-name-sans-versions`:

```
 This function returns FILENAME with any file version numbers,
 backup version numbers, or trailing tildes discarded.
 ...
 See also `file-name-version-regexp'.
```

`file-name-version-regexp`:

```
 Regular expression matching the backup/version part of a file name.
 Used by `file-name-sans-versions'.
```

If you can't get the behaviour you want using only the regexp, then
you would redefine `file-name-sans-versions` to have the behaviour
that you require.

My build of Emacs has the following default regexp:

```el
(defvar file-name-version-regexp
  "\\(?:~\\|\\.~[-[:alnum:]:#@^._]+\\(?:~[[:digit:]]+\\)?~\\)"
  ;; The last ~[[:digit]]+ matches relative versions in git,
  ;; e.g. `foo.js.~HEAD~1~'.
  "Regular expression matching the backup/version part of a file name.
Used by `file-name-sans-versions'.")
```